# Network Error while connecting backend to frontend (MERN stack used)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am making a web app and have made back-end with express, mongodb and node.js, while the frontend is made in React.js.
The backend runs completely fine on its own, when run using "nodemon server.js"
But when connected to frontend using axios, it throws "Network Error" error.

Here is my code to server.js (back-end, connecting url) and http-common.js (front-end, axios)

server.js

```
import cors from "cors";
import userquery from "./student/api/query.routes.js";
import admin from "./admin/api/admin.routes.js";
const app = express(); 
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use("/api/v1/user", userquery);  
app.use("/api/v1/admin", admin);
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({ error: "not found" });
}); 
export default app;
```

> query.routes.js

```
import QueryCtrl from "./query.controller.js";
import personalQueriesCtrl from "./personalQueries.controller.js";
import SubjectCtrl from "./subject.controller.js";
import UserCtrl from "./user.controller.js";
const router = express.Router(); //creates routes people can go to
router.route("/").get(QueryCtrl.apiGetQueries);
router.route("/signup").post(UserCtrl.apiPostUser);
router.route("/subjects").get(SubjectCtrl.apiGetSubjects);
router.route("/AskQuery").post(personalQueriesCtrl.apiPostQuery);
export default router;
```

http-common.js

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
  proxy: false,
});
```

Please help if you can!

Comment: What is the error? Also, please provide the code where you are making the call to the backend with axios.

Comment: Its ok, I have solved the error. The server was down.